# Referencing a CTE multiple times with different variables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, common-table-expression

In BigQuery, I have a table like this

| col_a | col_b | datetime_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2022-01-01 |
| 0 | 1 | 2022-01-01 |

I want to get aggregates from different dates like this

```
SELECT
SUM(sum_col_a) sum_col_a,
SUM(sum_col_b) sum_col_b,
FROM my_table
WHERE datetime_col BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

| sum_col_a | sum_col_b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

What I would like to achieve is run through the same query with different dates, like this

| date_name | sum_col_a | sum_col_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MTD | 1 | 1 |
| QTD | 1 | 1 |

So I effectively want to do something like

```
WITH my_cte AS (SELECT....the query above)
SELECT * FROM my_cte WHERE datetime_col BETWEEN '2022-06-01' AND '2022-06-22'
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM my_cte WHERE datetime_col BETWEEN '2022-04-01' AND '2022-06-22'
```

I thought one way would be to `DECLARE date1 DATE DEFAULT '2022-06-13';` at the top but then set them each time.

What is the correct way of doing this? Or do I need to repeat the entire `with` cause for each date range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below query. You can add more **date range** in **ranges** table.

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE ranges AS
SELECT 'MTD' date_name, DATE '2022-01-01' start_date, DATE '2022-01-31' end_date
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'QTD', '2022-01-01', '2022-03-31';

CREATE TEMP TABLE sample AS 
SELECT 1 col_a, 0 col_b, DATE '2022-01-01' datetime_col UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 1, '2022-01-31' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 0, '2022-02-01' UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 3, '2022-03-01';

SELECT date_name, SUM(col_a) sum_col_a, SUM(col_b) sum_col_b 
  FROM sample s 
  LEFT JOIN ranges r 
    ON datetime_col BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
 GROUP BY 1;
```

output:

[image]